# Right way to specify base address in WCF service with net.tcp

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, windows-services, lan

Suppose I've one WCF service hosted in a Windows service running on a machine on LAN. I want to make this service to be consumed by applications running on other machines on same LAN. Further assume I've hosted WCF service in a Windows service using TCP. So the app config file will have the base address mentioned something like this:

```
<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1" />
```

My question is will this service be accessed by clients over LAN though I've mentioned `localhost`? What is the right way to mention base address so that service could be consumed by clients on LAN? Is any arbitrary address is valid? If `localhost` is valid, which port shall I mention?

Comment: replace localhost with the machine's ip address

Comment: Does the IP address work with net.tcp? I need this architecture to be implemented across many LAN networks i.e. each LAN will have one machine on which Windows service is running and other machines on the same LAN should be able to access the service. In this case, do you mean that I have to mention IP address of host for each LAN? One more question: Is there any way to dynamically decide url of service on client side (e.g. user will enter url of service )?

Comment: For each machine runs your service, you will have to config its config accordingly (ip of the host), and you will have a config for your client specify the server's endpoint.

Comment: I mean to say do I have to mention different service urls for clients on different LAN? One more question: Is it possible to give facility to user to enter service address at run time?

Comment: Can I config both things programatically? I don't want to make it in app.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the actual ip. i think localhost is just for the current machine. localhost is an alias for the default address 127.0.0.1